# Is there any way I can connect Python to Minecraft? I'm trying to use mcpi library

Tags: python, minecraft

I'm currently working on a Python project that involves interacting with Minecraft using the `mcpi` library. However, I'm encountering issues, and I suspect it might be due to compatibility problems or incorrect setup. Here's what I've tried and the issues I'm facing:

1. Environment Setup:

- I'm using Python 3.11
- I've Installed `mcpi` library
- My Minecraft Version is 1.20.1
- I have created a local Minecraft server

2. Code I've tried:

```
from mcpi.minecraft import minecraft

mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()

mc.postToChat("Hello World")
```

3. Issues Encountered:
   I get this error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

4. Expected Outcome:
   `Hello World` in Minecraft Server Chat

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to make the `mcpi` library work with my Minecraft setup. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, are you using Minecraft: Pi Edition? The first sentence of the documentation for `mcpi` says (emphasis mine) "mcpi Python library for communicating with **Minecraft: Pi edition** and RaspberryJuice."

Comment: It seems that the Minecraft Pi edition requires a linux operating system! I am currently using Windows 11! @SilvioMayolo

Comment: Did you tried with IP and port specified as doc said ?https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/p/minecraft-api-reference.html